# Connecting sql server instance in intranet between VM on azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, networking, virtual-machine, ip-address

I have two VM on azure having IP address
1. VM 1 - 10.0.0.4
2. VM 2 - 10.0.0.5

Default gateway for both of them is 10.0.0.1

Both of these machines have their own SQL server instances.
I want to connect each instance from another machine on a local network of azure.

I am trying 10.0.0.4\sqlinstance from 10.0.0.5 however connection couldn't be established.

I checked ping on each other. Every possible ping is giving RTO probably because ICMP might be disabled.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

So I do not know what design are you using, but if those are on the same VNet the only thing that's blocking them is the VM level firewall. If those are on different VNet's that's a completely different story (Still solvable, you need to look at VNet peering or Site-to-Site VPN).